# How ?SPEVX LAPACK calculates eigenvectors?

Tags: gfortran, lapack, blas

I'm trying to use ?SPEVX to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Does anyone have a explanation to how ?SPEVX calculates eigenvectors? Because whenever I try to compare it to the analytical results, it doesn't match. My understanding is it ALWAYS generates real valued function, the question is HOW?
My understanding is linear combination of two eigenvectors (corresponding to this eigenvalue) will be a valid eigenvector! but how does this work? What is the linear combination.
Please help.

Thank you

I compared the eigenvectors to analytical function for such as exp(ix). The eigenvectors didn't match.

Comment: Hi Sheroz Khalid, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you give a [mre] of the problem, with complete input and output? Your question as it stands is quite broad, and a lot of it is about maths rather than programming. For more information, you might want to check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: I'm comparing the analytical and numerical results for the exponential function for the two degenerate states. My question might be more related to mathematics, but I need help understanding how eigenvectors are being generated from ?spevex. In essence I want to know how lapack makes the linear combination for degenerate states. I'm sorry for not being able to provide input/output that's because the question is related to the working of spevex.

Comment: The question of "how eigenvectors are being generated from ?spevex" is very broad, and is unlikely to get a good answer here. The related question, "how am I using ?spevex wrong and what should I do instead" is much more specific, and much more likely to get a helpful answer, but you'll have to give us much more information to get an answer for it.